# Change directory for mysql log_bin in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, mysql, log

Changing the directory of log_bin in mysql to a disk mounted by fstab.

```
vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

server-id = 1 
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

works fine but

```
vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

server-id = 1
log_bin = /media/disk1/mysql/mysql-bin.log 

chown -R mysql:mysql /media/disk1/mysql/
chmod 770 /media/disk1/mysql/
```

mysql can't be restarted.

Comment: @Rinzwind  it's ext4

Answer (score 0):

I find how to fix it

```
vim etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

/media/disk1/mysql/ r,
/media/disk1/mysql/** rw,

service apparmor restart
service mysql restart
```